# How is php child-process handled by OS

Tags: php

When PHP create child process using exec or pcntl_fork, how does the OS on a multi-core CPU handles it?
is the child-process passed on to another core.

Answer (score 1):

It handles it just like any other process. If the server only has one core, it will obviously run on the same core. If the server has multiple cores, it can run on the same or a different core, and this can vary over time.

Comment: And also could you explain me, how creating child process increases performance? My understanding is that parent process waits until child process is done, to continue.

Comment: `exec` waits, unless you put the command in the background by ending it with `&`. But `pcntl_fork` doesn't wait, the new process runs convurrently with the old one, and the parent process can even exit without waiting for the child to finish. This is all basic Unix process control, any OS textbook should explain it.